# Threat 1: Signal Sigabrt Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, breakpoints, sigabrt

I have developed a game, but now I am trying to add music to it.  It worked one time in the iPhone 3.5 Simulator, but now it crashes every time I run it.  What's up here?

```
NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Intro Soundtrack" ofType:@"mp3"];
audioPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
audioPlayer1.delegate = self;
audioPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer1 play]; // Exception breakpoint says it is this line, but what's wrong here?  I don't see anything wrong.
```

I am getting the Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research showed that I deleted IBOutlets in my code, but did not remove the connections in IB.  I removed them and it fixed the issue.